# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, unityads, applovin

I'm trying to implement UnityAds SDK to use with AppLovin Max mediation, but after updating the UnityAds SDK to it's latest version which is 3.7.0, i'm getting this error when trying to update the pods.

Any suggestions?

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "UnityAds":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    UnityAds (= 3.7.0)

  In Podfile:
    AppLovinMediationUnityAdsAdapter was resolved to 3.0.0.2, which depends on
      UnityAds (= 3.0.0)

    UnityAds (= 3.7.0)
```

Comment: AppLovinMediationUnityAdsAdapter needs a 3.0.0 version of `UnityAds`. You expect `3.7.0` yourself. They aren't compatible version. You need to find the version that "everyone depends on", uncluding sub-dependencies. But maybe that `AppLovinMediationUnityAdsAdapter` has a newer version that accept an newer version of `UnityAds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that when you are using AppLovinSDK MAX mediation and want to implement other mediation networks, you should **NOT** implement the other networks SDK's (which is what I did):

```
pod 'UnityAds'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
```

What you really should do is just to implement the adapters you want and they will include the SDK version which they support in by them self.

There is no proper documentation in AppLovin's website and all seems to be messed up there, but it's working the same as Google AdMob Mediation so that's how I figure it out and AppLovin's support team approved it right after.

This is how the `Podfile` should look using AppLovinSDK:

```
pod 'AppLovinSDK'
pod 'AppLovinMediationFacebookAdapter'
pod 'AppLovinMediationUnityAdsAdapter'
pod 'AppLovinMediationVungleAdapter'
pod 'AppLovinMediationGoogleAdapter'
```

And that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

The AppLovin adapters are specifically certified and tested against a specific version of the mediated networks' SDK. In this instance, it seems that the adapter version was `3.0.0.2` which likely depends on UnityAds SDK `3.0.0` (the first `n - 1` numbers represent the certified SDK's version).

I'd recommend removing explicit references to UnityAds in your Podfile.